# Layout with Bootstrap to hold calendars?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

I need to show 12 calendars.

I want it to show 6 per row at most, and if the browser is too small, I want it to just move the excess down.

Is this possible with boostrap?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. The twitter boostrap is based on 12 columns and it will automatically collapse downwards as the size of the screen changes. Just wrap each calendar in a `<div span2>` (12/6=2) and the framework will take care of the rest for you.

The bootstrap documentation for these things is very good. Refer to the [scaffolding system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) to get a better idea about how the grid system works.

edit: Just realized that the html/css I included to help you out didn't show up cause I forgot to wrap it with the code tags. `<div span2>` is what you need

Answer (score 3):

I believe you may be able to achieve the desired result by utilizing [Boostraps built in Grid System](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and some of its default css classes.

I created a test page with 12 `<asp:Calendar>` Objects. I placed each of these calendars within a `<div class="row">` and a `<div class="span12">` container.

Now that all the calendars are grouped within the divs, and the divs are set to be fluid via the bootstrap grid system, the container will resize with the browser. Now all we have to do is get the calendars to start shuffling downwards when the container gets resized.

In order to do that I added the built in `class="pull-left"` to each of my `<asp:calendar>` objects.

The result worked perfectly for me and may work to your liking.

Here is my test code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar3" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar4" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar5" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar6" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar7" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar8" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar9" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar10" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar11" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar12" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left"></asp:Calendar>
</div>
```

Even if you are not using the `<asp:Calendar>` objects, the `class="pull-left"` should work on whatever calendar you are using.

To add some spacing between the calendars you can create your own css class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .CalendarMargin {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }
</style>
```

Then add the new class to the `<asp:Calendar>` tags like so:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" CssClass="pull-left CalendarMargin"></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: How could I get some spacing both horizontally and vertically between calendars?